# How to set the text on action bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am working on android application in which i am using sherlock action bar. I want to change the text on my action bar programmatically when user clicked it. I have done it in Edit Text as:`editText.setText("Save");` when user clicked textView. I want to do it on run time when i clicked on action bar text it should be changed to "save" My code for action bar is given below:

[image]

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/editTxt"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        android:title="Edit"/>

</menu>

@Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
                com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.editTxt:
                return true;

            default:
                finish();
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        }
```

Comment: Check this question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059580/editing-text-in-action-bar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Changing `ActionBar` title**

If you're running API >= 11, then :

```
getActionBar().setTitle("Hello");
```

Or, with API < 11 :

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Hello");
```

To change the ActionBar's text.

**EDIT: Changing MenuItem text on click**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.editTxt:
            item.setTitle("Hello");
            return true;

  ......
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please see my edited question. I only want to change the text name of the field on Action Bar. I don't want to change the Title. I am using Sherlock actionbar

Comment: It seems to be an Action Button, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Its a action button. Kindly please also guide me how to change the color of action button too. Thanks and appreciations